# DocuSign for Salesforce Automatic Reminders

Tags: opportunity, docusign

I have "send with docuSign" button on opportunity and need to send opportunity details as PDF with docuSign.
Also we have send reminder based on one date field on opportunity.

So suppose if i sent document today with docuSign and if date field say 3 days after document send date , i have to send the reminder to recipient.
Remainder should send based on date field whatever date it is.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using minimum automation, this is a fairly straightforward task.

The DocuSign managed package installs an object called "DocuSign Status". This object has a lookup to the opportunity that you will take advantage of.

Create a process builder for this object that fires when it's created and each time it is edited to meet criteria.

This PB should use a time based action to fire a pre-made email alert to the specified user if the "status" field is not "completed" by the reminder date.

Here are some documents that might help you:

- [Email Alert Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_wfalerts.htm&type=5)
- [Process Builder Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/projects/quickstart-process-builder)
- [DocuSign Admin Documentation](https://support.docusign.com/guides/dfs-admin-guide-overview-admin)

### Advanced

I just completed a POC for a completely automated DocuSign send using their Rest API in Salesforce. You're fairly limited in what you can do using the method above. For instance, your reminder email will not be able to contain a link to the document to be signed meaning if the end user for some reason loses the original email they will have to request a new document from you.

I'd recommend a seniored SF developer or a consulting service for a more advanced integration.

Comment: Thanks for the update, i think i have use API call docuSign and send oppty detail as pdf using docuSign without single click whenever oppty stage is document sent.

Comment: I have done something very simmilar this past week. It's very doable but it'll require reading alot of API docs the DocuSign docs are pretty terrible IMO (several links go to 404 and there are links that just cycle you back to the same page as well as an incomplete list of the available properties). If you have specific questions feel free to reach back out.